# Does it "damage" a joomla website to test extensions?

Tags: joomla, joomla2.5, joomla-extensions

I have a bit of bad habbit, I install joomla on xampp and test all extensions and things im planning to add on the website there. Then I go to live website and try to start it from scratch, but it get very confusing and stressing this way..

I am thinking of just uploading the xampp joomla site to a live server but I am worried about these things:

I have installed/uninstalled some extensions (10+) do these leave behind any corrupted files in general or cause any problems?

Any tips cause im really worried now, the website has grown a lot and I cant start it from start even looking at the notes I took while making it. Uninstalled extensions do they leave any files behind or cause any problems? Right now the website works good on XAMPP.

Any tips or suggestions greatly appreciated,
Ammy

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most extensions uninstall fairly cleanly. You can be sure by using an FTP client and looking under /components, /plugins, and /modules (and/or their counterparts under /administrator) for leftover directories with the extension's name. You can also use PHPMyAdmin or somesuch to look for leftover database tables with similar names.

Even if files and tables are left behind, they're unlikely to cause problems with the site. I understand the desire to keep a tidy codebase, but that's not a good reason to build a site twice.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. You wont imagine the confusion. Every edit in code or css writing it on a notepad and then after the site is done trying to redo everything from start. (maybe im paranoid lol) I will try to just transfer the site and see any problems within the folders you said and via PHPMyAdmin. Really appreciate your help, thank you!

Comment: I think I can imagine, which is why I'd never do it that way. :-) You're welcome.

Comment: If I can piggyback here - be sure and use Akeeba Backup - it makes taking sites from localhost situations to live servers a breeze.  It's a great way to make routine backups of your sites so that should they ever go down, the host server blows up, whatever reason - you have a backup!!  It's pretty much the primary thing anyone on the forums will tell you.  Isherwood covered everything about your main question but I wanted to chime in about Akeeba Backup to make your life even easier!  Cheers.

Comment: Absolutely. I consider Akeeba one of my must-haves, along with JCE/MediaBox.

Comment: I thank you truly both for your help, I have just downloaded Akeeba. From your experience if a Joomla website is working from start if I only do posts and no further editing/plugins or changes does it "brake" by its own? Im new in the Joomla area. My biggest fear is it works today and in 3days it goes berserk. Thats why I went the paranoid way with my other sites and did them 2 times. Again thanks

Comment: My experience is that everything works pretty well and just keeps working. I just want to add that if you are working on XAMPP, an FTP client is not necessary. You can just open the folder on your computer, since you are running on localhost. I would also agree that even if something is left behind the worst case scenario is that your install takes some extra file space than it normally would (which is usually minor on most hosting accounts)

Comment: Joomla is a mature and stable platform. It will neither brake nor break with simple content creation. However, it will prompt you to update Joomla's core and most extensions automatically. There's always the (very small) potential that something will go wrong at that point. That said, it's far better to keep your site updated for security than to worry about the rare case of an update problem.

Comment: Thank you for your reply, really appreciate it and comforting in the panic and confusion :)

Answer (score 1):

Most extensions delete their files on an uninstall. This is because Joomla does this job itself, the extension doesn't have to do anything for this to work.

However the tables are a different beast. While it would be very easy for extensions to delete their tables on uninstall, there are different ideas about this. Some argue that they don't want to be responsible for deleted data and thus leave the tables behind.
Also entries in the assets, categories, tags mappings and menu tables are likely to be lying around after an uninstall. Most extensions will not clean those tables up during uninstall.

There may also be leftovers in files, if the extension used some library like fof or similar. There is no ckeck if the uninstalled extension was the last one that used that library. So you need to uninstall those manually, but you need to know if it's used or not.

The leftover tables and entries don't generate any problems except for a bit more memory usage. However a leftover library may be a huge security issue as it may contain a bug which could be abused. Since no extension is using it anymore, it will never get updated and the bug doesn't get fixed.